# consuming mySQL database with windows phone 7

Tags: mysql, web-services, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, webserver

I have a mysql database on my website, and I am trying to find a way to transfer this data (only a list of html URLs for pictures I update manually) to my Windows Phone 7 to be read in a listbox.

However I just learned that my website offers a Ruby and Rails version which is prone to easy hacking. I have absolutely no clue how to accomplish this task, and all the tutorials I've seen and read just can't help me on my task, as they're so varied.

I have wordpress and PHP available as my options now.

Can anyone please list out the steps I have to do (or at least google) so I can get this task out of sight and mind?

Answer (score 0):

You should not access your database directly. You rather should wrap such access up. If you have php, you can create a php site offering your application on the phone a xml file (or an xml formated page) with the desired information and let the php access your database.